# Regex to match new lines created by automatic word wrapping

Tags: google-docs, regex

Google Docs find/replace supports regex but I've been unable to find a regular expression that will match new lines created by automatic word wrapping.

Is there any way in Google Docs to match new lines created by word wrapping as opposed to those created by  pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: I think there's a semantic issue here. If I understood you correctly, you are talking about typing words until there's no more width space and if you keep typing you'll be typing below in a "new line"; did I get it? If that's the case, that is not a newline. You'll find no trace of it being a new line because as far as Google, your computer, the universe, and any programmer, there's nothing making that as a new line. It's the same line, only wrapped down for space purposes. New lines keep being new lines even if you set your type size to a tiny number. I hope that clarifies something.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\v` to match non-¶ newlines.